# Unit testing CLI/MFC Application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mfc, c++-cli

I have CLI/MFC application and I would like to begin to learn how to unit test with it.  I have VS2008 Pro.  If possible, I would like to use the built in unit testing.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success with both [CPPUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit) and [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).  For either you have to do a bit of work to get the test results to integrate back into Studio.  The granularity of the results you want directly affects how much work.  Do you want a pass/fail for the whole test set, or individual results?  The former is a simple msbuild task, the latter requires outputting the result set to XML, massaging that with a transform, then pulling it back in.

Comment: For either of these, are there ways to test the CLI side of the application?

Comment: I've never tried, but probably not.  mstest can already handle managed C++.

Comment: Are there any examples of doing the latter, (that is, outputting the results to XML and loading them back in to VS)?

Answer (score 0):

We use Gallio & MbUnit to test our MFC & C++/CLI application. Simply write the tests in C++/CLI then you can test both managed and unmanged code in a single framework. We also use NMock2 for mocking the managed code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Team Test edition, you can use it to test C++/CLI applications and libraries. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243171.aspx).